# Shader Turning Grey instead of White

Tags: shaders

so I was following a tutorial on making detailed eyes, I don't know why but as I was making the shader, it's colouring the eye grey even though the gradient is clearly set to white?
Here's a picture of my shader,
[image: Eye]
As you can see, it's set to white, but even if I drag the gradient to fully white, it still looks a light grey...
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: For reference, here is the tutorial I was following, https://youtu.be/E0JyyWeptSA?t=558
You can see even though it appears my settings are the exact same, his is a consistent white in the middle, whereas mine is a dark grey...

Comment: Your gradient texture is set to Spherical, whereas the YouTube author's version is set to Linear. There may be other similar inconsistencies that are more relevant to your issue, though, so you might want to review your entire node configuration.

Comment: He said to put it on spherical, if you rewind a few seconds from the link i posted you can see it's set to spherical. I've gone over my nodes twice, even redid them from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Z translation to 0 instead of -0.5 in the mapping node. What you are seeing here is a cross-section along the bottom of the sphere gradient, instead of the middle cross-section.

Illustration :

[image]

Comment: Oh, that fixed it! Thank you!